# How to counter at even numbers only

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot surface pressure on a basemap. I have successfully extracted the pressure values as a numpy array. When I plotted the pressure value, it looks clumsy and isolines are very close. I would like to plot only even numbers (pressure values) of numpy array?

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Got a minimal reproducible example of the problem? :)

Comment: new_array = [];
if ( pressure_value % 2 == 0 ){
     new_array.push(pressure_value)
}
plot(pressure_value).

Not sure about the python sintaxe, but the logic should be something like that

Comment: So, do you want to remove all the odd entries, or do you want to round them to the nearest even value?

Comment: I dont want to round those odd them. I just want to `hide` or `mask` or not to be plotted.

Comment: But how _do_ you plot them? Will the pressure lines plot right if there are zeros in the array? How are the pressures represented in the array at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want, or how your data is reprensented, but this might work:

Assuming you have a two-dimensional numpy array holding the air pressure in different regions:

```
In [12]: A
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

You can use `A % 2` to get the modulo 2 for each cell, as a new array:

```
In [13]: A % 2
Out[13]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

You can just add those two, to get a new array where `1` is added to each odd cell, bumping all the numbers in the array up to the next even number:

```
In [14]: A + (A % 2)
Out[14]: 
array([[ 2,  2,  4],
       [ 4,  6,  6],
       [ 8,  8, 10]])
```

Now there are no more regions with odd pressure (they now have the same pressure as the next region with even pressure) and consequently there should not be any odd pressure lines.

Comment: I have built up my code using your example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you mean even values or even index positions. Here are both.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
even_index=x[::2]
even_values=x[x%2==0]
```

Comment: I don't think that OP want to skip the odd indices. That would just reduce the resolution of the plot, not get rid of the odd pressure lines. Removing the odd values _might_ be what he has in mind, but IMHO this will also not work, as it will alter the indices of the remaining elements, so they can no longer be associated with their original location. Also, seems not to work with 2D arrays. Of course, OP did not say anything about any of this, so this is all just guesswork...